# Cofinality of $j(\kappa)$ for a measurability embedding $j:V\to M$ with critical point $\kappa$

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, large-cardinals

Suppose $\kappa$ is a measurable cardinal and $j:V\to M$ is the ultrapower by a normal measure on $\kappa$. Let's say, for instance, that $2^\kappa=\kappa^{++}$ (note that this assumption has consistency strength greater than just a measurable cardinal). It is easy to see that $j(\kappa)$ has size $\kappa^{++}$ in $V$. So the cofinality of $j(\kappa)$ in $V$ can be either $\kappa^+$ or $\kappa^{++}$ (it cannot be $\kappa$ because $M$ is closed under $\kappa$-sequences). Can each of these possibilities be realized in some model of set theory? More generally, what can be said about the cofinality of $j(\kappa)$ under various GCH assumptions?

As Asaf Karagila notes in the comments below, we can reformulate the question to ask what are the possible cofinalities of the order $\kappa^\kappa/U$ for a normal measure $U$ on $\kappa$. This is equivalent because elements of $j(\kappa)$ are precisely the equivalence classes of functions $f:\kappa\to\kappa$.

Comment: That's a very nice question! You can transform it into just asking what is the cofinality of the order $\kappa^\kappa/U$. This should reduce it to a model theoretic question, methinks.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Actually it is precisely your reformulation that I am interested in.

Comment: It's a good thing that I stopped by, then. :)

Comment: You might want to add the model theoretic formulation to your question, by the way, and perhaps the [tag:model-theory] tag also.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Done!

Comment: Suppose $\kappa$ is supercompact and Laver indestructible. Given any regular $\lambda > \kappa$ do a $<\kappa$-support iteraton where at successor steps we add a function $f: \kappa \to \kappa$ where $f$ is eventually above any ground model function. $\kappa$ remains supercompact in the extension and the functions introduced during the iteration should witness the cofinality is equal to $\lambda$ (with respect to any normal measure on $\kappa$).

Comment: @MohammadGolshani: The length of the iteration can be an ordinal. By controlling the cofinality of the length of iteration you will get any desirable cofinality (above $\kappa$) for $j(\kappa)$. For example, if the length of the  iteration is $\kappa^{++} + \kappa^{+}$ you will get $2^\kappa = \kappa^{++}$ and $\text{cf } j(\kappa) = \kappa^{+}$. This way you can get full independence between $2^\kappa$ and $\text{cf } j(\kappa)$.

Comment: @YairHayut Yes! I think this fully answers the question. Can you expand your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Vika, I read the question as asking if you can realize in the same model both options. So I'm not sure of Yair's comment answers that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I should have done a better job stating my question clearly. I  wanted to know precisely what Yair answered: whether there are models where $\text{cf}(j(\kappa))$ is smaller than the size of $j(\kappa)$. Your interpretation of the question is very interesting as well, but I think much harder to answer.

Comment: Alright, then. Then @Yair really did answer your question. The harder question is interesting. I don't know about harder, I think the answer just lies in a less expected place (e.g., some model theory or even PCF theory argument to give some characterization of the cofinality in terms of the ultrafilter, and then forcing to get these situations to happen).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I edited the question to make it clearer. Maybe I will ask your version as a follow-up if you don't ask it first :).

Comment: Go ahead, I have too many things on my head in the coming week and a half. But first let Yair post his answer. Knowing him, there's a reasonable chance he'll kill two birds with one stone. :) (And I can already see the look on his face when he'll read this comment! Ha! :D)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Mohammad Golshani remarked, it is possible to control the cofinality of $j(\kappa)$ by iterating the forcing that adds a function $f\colon \kappa \to \kappa$ which is eventually larger than any ground model function.

The conditions of the forcing notion are pairs of the form $(s, g)$ where $s{\in} ^{<\kappa}\kappa$ and $g\colon \kappa \to \kappa$, where $(s, g)$ is stronger than $(t, h)$ if $s\supseteq t$, $g \geq h$ everywhere and $\forall \alpha \in \text{dom } s \setminus \text{dom }t$, $s(\alpha) \geq h(\alpha)$.

Assuming $\kappa^{<\kappa} = \kappa$, this forcing is $\kappa$-centred and $\kappa$-directed closed. Let $\mathbb{P}_\alpha$ be the iteration of adding dominating function for $\alpha$ many steps with support ${<}\kappa$. Using the $\kappa$-closure of iteration and standard $\Delta$-system arguments - this iteration is $\kappa^{+}$-c.c. Therefore, it doesn't collapse cardinals.

Let $\langle f_i \mid i < \alpha\rangle$ be the sequence of the generic dominating functions.

**Lemma:** If $\text{cf }\alpha \geq \kappa^{+}$ then the true cofinality of $\kappa^{\kappa} / J^{bd}$ is $\text{cf }\alpha$. Namely, there is a cofinal, increasing sequence of functions in $\kappa^{\kappa}$ of order type $\text{cf }\alpha$.

**Proof:** Let $\lambda = \text{cf }\alpha$. Let $\langle \gamma_i \mid i < \lambda\rangle$ be a cofinal sequence. The sequence of functions $g_i = f_{\gamma_i}$ is increasing (modulo bounded error) and by the chain condition of $\mathbb{P}_\alpha$, every function in the generic extension is bounded by one of them. $\square$

Let $\kappa$ be a measurable cardinal. If $\text{tcf } \kappa^{\kappa} / J^{bd} = \lambda$, then for every $\kappa$-complete measure $\mathcal{U}$ on $\kappa$, $\text{cf }j_{\mathcal{U}}(\kappa) = \lambda$. Therefore, in order to construct a model in which $\text{cf }j(\kappa) = \lambda$, $2^\kappa = \mu$ where $\kappa < \lambda \leq \mu$, $\lambda$ regular, $\text{cf } \mu \geq \kappa^{+}$, we may start with indestructible supercompact $\kappa$ such that $2^\kappa = \kappa^{+}$ and force with $\mathbb{P}_{\mu + \lambda}$.

Comment: Is it provable that $\kappa^\kappa/\mathcal J^{bd}$ has a true cofinality in the case of a measurable cardinal?

Comment: It's even enough for the non stationary ideal to have true cofinality in this case, when you think about it.